# bar chart fails to add first and last x-axis labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgf-core

For some reason the first and last x-axis labels are not printing on this bar chart. More labels are there (though not all) if less columns exist in the table (e.g. 3).

Any thoughts on how I can get the first and last x-axis labels to render with all the bars are greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    interval   & IF & SW & CB & IFSWITCH & CUBESWITCH & IFCUBE & ALL \\
    0--1.3     & 0  & 0 & 0  & 1  & 3401  & 0    & 120816 \\
    1.3--1.5   & 2  & 0 & 0  & 3  & 15997 & 2614 & 20412  \\
    1.5--1.57  & 7  & 0 & 0  & 1  & 7083  & 10   & 6080   \\
    1.57--1.8  & 14 & 0 & 0  & 6  & 6428  & 625  & 9248   \\
    1.8--2.0   & 8  & 1 & 5  & 8  & 4993  & 171  & 3358   \\
    2.0--3.0   & 6  & 3 & 22 & 30 & 3302  & 164  & 1963   \\
    3.0--4.0   & 1  & 0 & 32 & 3  & 675   & 17   & 115    \\
    4.0--5.0   & 3  & 0 & 12 & 1  & 243   & 7    & 25     \\
    5.0--10    & 5  & 0 & 55 & 5  & 366   & 7    & 31     \\
    10--100    & 2  & 0 & 47 & 2  & 152   & 1    & 8      \\
    100--600   & 0  & 0 & 3  & 0  & 2     & 0    & 0      \\
    }\mydataOptimal
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
     ymode=log,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        xticklabel style={rotate=40,font=\small},
        ymajorgrids = true,
            ybar,
            bar width=0.1cm,%<- changed
            width=\textwidth,
            height=.5\textwidth,
            legend style={at={(0.56,1)},
                anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={0--1.3, 1.3--1.5, 1.5--1.57, 1.57--1.8, 1.8--2.0, 2.0--3.0, 3.0--4.0, 4.0--5.0, 5.0--10, 10--100, 100--600},
            xtick=data,
            ymin=1,
            ymax=180000,
            ylabel={Count of Settings},
            xlabel={$\mu$ seconds},
        ]
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=IF]{\mydataOptimal};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=SW]{\mydataOptimal};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=CB]{\mydataOptimal};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=IFSWITCH]{\mydataOptimal};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=CUBESWITCH]{\mydataOptimal};
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=IFCUBE]{\mydataOptimal};        
        \addplot table[x=interval,y=ALL]{\mydataOptimal};        
        \legend{If, Switch, Cube, If+Switch,Cube+Switch,If+Cube,All}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

labels existing with less columns in the data:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The code was updated to compile independently. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xtick=data` makes `ticks` where there is data in the *first* `\addplot`. With a logarithmic y axis `ymode=log`, you can not use the value `0`. All bars with `y=0` is dropped from the plot - see the log.

You can use

```
xtick={0--1.3, 1.3--1.5, 1.5--1.57, 1.57--1.8, 1.8--2.0, 2.0--3.0, 3.0--4.0, 4.0--5.0, 5.0--10, 10--100, 100--600},
xticklabels={0--1.3, 1.3--1.5, 1.5--1.57, 1.57--1.8, 1.8--2.0, 2.0--3.0, 3.0--4.0, 4.0--5.0, 5.0--10, 10--100, 100--600},
```

instead of `xtick=data`